# PHP install filled directory to server from url

Tags: php, html, installation, uploading

I've written a very basic cms and would like to be able to deploy it easier. This means, get the user to download one php file, which would then install all the files from a server, setup the database and tables, user info etc...

Is there an easy(ish) way to do this. I would like to do this myself to be able to give it my own twist.

If there isn't an easy way to do this, are there any good php install scripts that could do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Down a free forum like phpbb and see what their install files look like. You wouldn't want to store info on your own database otherwise people would download the _one_ file with your database connections and that's it for your database...